# Передать значение let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard класса ViewController: UIViewController в класс ViewController2: UIViewController!

Tags: xcode, swift, mobile-development

Как сохранять данные внутри класса я разобрался, а как их передать в поле другого класса? У меня для каждого View Controller свой класс UIViewController.

Comment: `vc1.field = vc2.field;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Создайте в одном ViewController глобальную переменную:

```
public var <ваша переменная> 
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
   <код контроллера>
}
```

И теперь можете обратиться к этой переменной из другого ViewController`а

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
   <ваша переменная> — можете обращаться к ней так
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался, получилось! А как мне сохранять данные на неограниченное время? Я заметил что после рестарта операционки данные теряются...

Comment: Нужно использовать БД, наверное. Почитайте про CoreData